# elasticsearch exists filter in java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a question...
I want to use the `exists` filter combined with an aggregation in my **java** query to get results if the field has any value. It's a nested array, so I want to get the elements that have any value in the array.
In my java code I have this:

```
ExistsFilterBuilder filter=FilterBuilders.existsFilter("guides");
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(),filter);
TermsBuilder tbBrand = AggregationBuilders.terms("brand-ag").field("brand.name.name.raw").order(Terms.Order.term(true)).size(0);

SearchResponse sr = esClient.prepareSearch("cellphones").setTypes("cellphone").setQuery(qb)
                .addAggregation(tbBrand ).execute().actionGet();
```

my object class has the field "guides" as a nested object:

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
private List<EquipoVideoTutorialDTO> guides;
```

the brand aggregation is an object:

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Object)
private CatalogoDTO brand;
```

this returns an empty array, but i know i have at least 1 item...

this query results in this:

```
{
  "filtered" : {
    "query" : {
      "match_all" : { }
    },
    "filter" : {
      "exists" : {
        "field" : "guides"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

posting the code, what I want is:
get all "brands" names (the aggregation) from an index where the element has some value in "guides" attribute.

Am I missing something?

**edit**

I add an example element **with** guides

```
{
        "idEquipo": 3675,
        "tipoTerminal": {
            "id": 1,
            "nombre": "TELEFONO"
        },
        "brand": {
            "id": 34,
            "nombre": "Apple"
        },
        "sistemaOperativo": {},
        "versionSO": null,
        "idUnico": "3521",
        "nombreComercial": null,
        "modelo": "iPhone 5s",
        "descripcion": "El iPhone siempre ha sido un dispositivo de vanguardia, y el iPhone 5s es exactamente eso. con una arquitectura móvil de 64 bits sin precedentes, un sensor identificador de huellas digitales innovador, y un flash doble LED, es un Smartphone que está adelantado a su tiempo. Todas estas funcionalidades están al servicio de las personas, y no al revés: son la prueba de que la innovación, cuidadosamente pensada, supera la tecnología desenfrenada. Esto se llama progreso. Y es algo hermoso.",
        "capacidadesDiferentes": [
            {
                "value": "Visual"
            },
            {
                "value": "Motriz"
            },
            {
                "value": "Auditiva - Habla"
            }
        ],
        "destacado": null,
        "precioMasBajo": null,
        "fechaCreacion": "2013-10-11",
        "fechaUltimaModificacion": "2014-08-13",
        "coberturaRoamingInternacional": [],
        "videos": [],
        "tutoriales": [],
        "guides": [
            {
                "titulo": "Internet",
                "subtitulo": null,
                "descripcion": "Esta guía te ayudará a configurar tu equipo para que puedas navegar en Internet.",
                "pdf": null,
                "prioridad": 1
            }
        ],
        "tecnologias": [
            {
                "idTecnologia": 600,
                "tecnologia": "3G",
                "frecuencias": [
                    {
                        "frecuencia": "900"
                    },
                    {
                        "frecuencia": "850"
                    },
                    {
                        "frecuencia": "1900"
                    },
                    {
                        "frecuencia": "2100"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "idTecnologia": 100,
                "tecnologia": "GSM",
                "frecuencias": [
                    {
                        "frecuencia": "850"
                    },
                    {
                        "frecuencia": "900"
                    },
                    {
                        "frecuencia": "1800"
                    },
                    {
                        "frecuencia": "1900"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "idTecnologia": 800,
                "tecnologia": "4GLTE",
                "frecuencias": [
                    {
                        "frecuencia": "700"
                    },
                    {
                        "frecuencia": "1700"
                    },
                    {
                        "frecuencia": "2100"
                    },
                    {
                        "frecuencia": "850"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "versiones": [],
        "categorias": [],
        "version": null,
        "estatus": "P",
        "buckets": {}
    }
```

Comment: Can you show a sample document that should come back in the results?

Comment: i sure can, i just edited the post... ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out...

since the list is a nested object, you need to do a nested query for the filter:

```
ExistsFilterBuilder filter=FilterBuilders.existsFilter("guides");
NestedFilterBuilder nested=FilterBuilders.nestedFilter("guides", filter);
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(),nested);
TermsBuilder tbBrand = AggregationBuilders.terms("brand-ag").field("brand.name.name.raw").order(Terms.Order.term(true)).size(0);

SearchResponse sr = esClient.prepareSearch("cellphones").setTypes("cellphone").setQuery(qb)
            .addAggregation(tbBrand ).execute().actionGet();
```